Get Transformed Box Coordinates in Javascript (getBoxQuads)
I've created a polyfill for the getBoxQuads API (https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/03/introducing-the-getboxquads-api/), but it does not work if I use transform in css with perspective in it. (see my sample app here: https://jogibear9988.github.io/getBoxQuadsPolyfill/), the overlay for these 2 boxes is wrong:

source is here: https://github.com/jogibear9988/getBoxQuadsPolyfill
What did I do in the polyfill? I combine all the transform applied to an element, I apply a translateTransform for it's offset position and multiply with a the parent transforms.
But somehow this only works for 2D.
The resulting Point has a "z" value where the overlay is wrong, but I don't know how to convert back to 2D.
